# Adhoc Data processing / ETL

Tags: email, etl, street-address

I've just started at a new company in outsourced communications (e.g. print and mail, email, fax). One of the requirements is to process clients data and get it ready for mailing.

For recurring jobs, this is easy using an ETL tool linked in with some addressing software, but for adhoc stuff it's a bit overkill. I've used inhouse developed stuff before (clunky but usable), but I don't want to have to re-develop that here. Any recommendations?

Some features :

- Basic DBMS functionality (preferably with a proper DBMS backend for SQL support)
- Field concatenation (e.g. combine Firstname + Surname)
- "Pushing columns" (e.g. with address fields 1 - 8, push them left so if one is blank, the next one gets pushed up)
- Australia post mail sorting and dpid allocation (or can link into external tools relatively easily)

Answer (score 1):

Would rolling your own with Python or Perl be acceptable?